# Displaying a textview on 2 lines (with any string length)

Tags: java, android

I have a string array as follows:
["Hello", "Say Goodbye", "I am a Developer", "Java is an object-oriented language", "Web application programming,...]

I want to display them on the TextView with 2 lines if the string more than one word, and the number of characters difference between 2 lines is the lowest.

For example: "Web application programming" should be "Web application\nprogramming", not "Web\napplication programming".

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: please post minimal reproducible code and let us know what did you try so far.

Comment: You need to go throw the strings and manipulate them before assigning them to the TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suit your problem:

```
private String wrapText(String in) {
    String r;
    if(in.contains(" ")) {
        int middle = in.length() / 2;
        int before = getSpaceBeforeIndex(in, middle);
        int after = getSpaceAfterIndex(in, middle);

        int rightOne;

        if(before == -1) {
            rightOne = after;
        } else if(after == -1) {
            rightOne = before;
        } else {
            rightOne = (middle - before) < (after - middle)? before : after;
        }

        r = in.substring(0, rightOne) + "\n" + in.substring(rightOne);
    } else {
        r = in;
    }

    return r;
}

private static int getSpaceBeforeIndex(String in, int index) {
    String cut = in.substring(0, index);
    int firstSpace = cut.lastIndexOf(" ");
    return firstSpace;
}

private static int getSpaceAfterIndex(String in, int index) {
    int nextSpace = in.indexOf(" ", index);
    return nextSpace;
}
```